# Pytorch Multiclass Classification 2D Tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, multiclass-classification

I am using `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` and it only excepts 1D tensors. I am performing binary classification, which i know can be done, but after reading all the posts on the same topic i can't seem to get it to work.

My data shape is:

```
out.shape = torch.size([1,4])
target.shape = torch.size([1,2])
```

And after running

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
for graphs in training_loader:
    out = model(graphs.x, graphs.edge_index, graphs.batch)
    loss = criterion(out, graphs.y)
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/polar/venv/pygeo/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3526, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-19-29fe12a317a0>", line 1, in <module>
    loss = criterion(out, graphs.y.squeeze_(dim=1))
  File "/home/polar/venv/pygeo/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/polar/venv/pygeo/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py", line 1174, in forward
    return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
  File "/home/polar/venv/pygeo/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 3029, in cross_entropy
    return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
RuntimeError: 0D or 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported
```

I have tried `graphs.y.squeeze` and `torch.max(graphs.y, 1)[0]` to no avail. I need the predictions to output 4 logits for the probability of the 4 classes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true that `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss` expects 1D tensors. The API documentation specifically states otherwise.

That said, the prediction and target tensors need to have the same shape for cross entropy loss to make sense. If your prediction tensor has a shape of `(1, 4)`, it means you have a batch size of 1 and predictions (logits) for 4 classes. Yet, your target tensor has a shape of `(1, 2)`, so a batch size of 1 but labels for only 2 classes. Of course, if you're missing two classes between your prediction and your label, no loss can be calculated, no matter how you reshape the tensors.